# Android studio - android emulator doesn't work correctly

Tags: android-studio, adb, android-imagebutton

Yesterday I was trying to add ImageButton to my project,today I was surprised, when I tried to run an emulator,this is what i saw.

[image]

I'm think it's something with my ImageButton - I was trying to make it in different ways, but none worked.

Comment: Please describe your exact problem and add some code

Answer (score 0):

Try different elements to see if they behave the same.
Also i'd suggest try to run the project in a real device. Sometimes emulator and real device behave different and, at the end of the day its in a real device where you want it to work properly.

Comment: I'm just created now a new project,and it's change nothing. So I think it's something with the IDE. I'll try to reinstall it. I'm started it on real device,it works (except Image Buttons).

Comment: did you assign an image to the button right? might be the kind of image you are using?